# How may I access an attribute of a class from the __init__ of another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, object

I'm working on an OOP task, as we've just been introduced to it.
We are to create two classes: `Animal` and `Desert`
They have specified for us a variety of attributes and methods that these classes must have

`Desert` contains a `Grid` attribute that some `Animal` objects should be distributed on.
`Animal` objects are represented with an `'A'` where present on the grid, but also store their position locally, with their attributes `Across` and `Down`.

Within `__init__` of the `Animal` class, we are supposed to choose a random position on the `Grid` to place the animal. This means setting the  `Across` and `Down` attributes to a random value but also modifying the `Grid` to display an `'A'` in this location.

I'm not sure how I would go about accessing `Grid` from the `Animal` objects though.  Here is the relevant code, the comments relate to the different bullet points of the task:

```py
class Animal(Desert):

  # Constructor
  def __init__(self):

    # Generate a pair of random numbers between 0 and 39.
    rand_num1 = randint(0, 39)
    rand_num2 = randint(0, 39)

    # Place an animal at that random position.
    self.Across = rand_num1
    self.Down = rand_num2
    # HERE IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO MODIFY THE GRID ATTRIBUTE OF DESERT

    # Initialise the animal's score to 0.
    self.Score = 0
```

```py
class Desert:

  # Constructor
  def __init__(self):


    # attributes:
    self.Grid = []
    self.StepCounter = 0
    self.AnimalList = []
    self.NumberofAnimals = 0

    # Initialises an empty grid
    self.Grid = [['ロ' * 40] * 40]

    # Creates 5 animal objects which are added to the AnimalList
    for _ in range(5):
      self.AnimalList.append(Animal())
```

Comment: Regarding your class hierarchy: an `Animal` *is-a* `Desert`? That sounds weird to me.

Comment: But if an `Animal` *is* a `Desert`, and you call the superclass `__init__` implementation correctly, then it's just `self.Grid`.

Comment: Your `self.Grid = [['ロ' * 40] * 40]` is not doing what you want. If you want a real matrix, use this: `self.Grid = [['ロ'] * 40 for _ in range(40)]`. If you use `*` instead of `range`, you will have copies and changing one element will result in a total of 40 changed elements since they are all references to the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to reconsider the relationship between Animal and Desert.  If you look at the init of the Desert, it should give you some indication.  The Desert have a list of animals, which is a has-a relationship with Animal.  You can read it as, the Desert has a Animal rather than the Animal is a Desert.  From this modeling relationship you may do something like this to access the Desert's grid.

The Desert may have a function that add animal, and that function as you add a new animal you can pass the grid as a parameter to the Animal constructor.  Something like this,

```
 #Animal __init__
 # Constructor
   def __init__(self, grid):
      ...


 # Desert __init__
 ....
 # Creates 5 animal objects which are added to the AnimalList
 for _ in range(5):
   self.AnimalList.append(Animal(self.Grid))
```

Also remove the inheritance from Desert for Animal.